# Does using PK violation as way of checking for existence reduce DB performance?

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

I'm using a python library that inserts tasks into a DB, with a few tens of tasks every second. Every task has a unique identifier, and if the task already exists in the DB the library updates it instead.

The way the library does it is always inserting, catching the PK violation error from the DB and updating.

Is there a cost to using this method of constant PK violation instead of selecting first to see whether the task already exists or using ON CONFLICT? Does some error-handling get invoked in the DB every time, causing reduced performanc? This is an external library and I would like to know if I should implement the logic myself. The specific DB I'm using is postgres, if it makes a difference.

Comment: Why no use `insert ... on conflict do nothing`?

Comment: As I said, it's an external library I use. I could make changes locally or just write the logic myself, but I want to know what's the cost of using it as it's currently written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking for existence as a separate step from insertion is definitely NOT the right way to go.  This is bad from a performance perspective (two round trips to the database) and bad from a data consistency perspective (two threads could both attempt to insert the same value at the same time).

Catching the primary key error still requires two round trips to the database, which incurs additional overhead.  Of course, the database is handling the data integrity, so you don't have race conditions -- unless you are also deleting/modifying the primary key.

The *best* solution is to let the database handle data integrity.  That is, use `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE`.

Whether you want to change a working library is a different issue.  Sometimes, a tested, reliable, inferior solution is simpler to keep than the perfect solution.